# CSS transform rotate always clockwise without exceeding 360 degrees

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Im designing a clock, for the "hands" Im using a combination of JS and CSS to make an smooth animation, converting second, minutes and hours to its corresponding degree in the analog clock:

```
function clock() { 
  var t = moment(),
      s = t.seconds() * 6,
      a = t.minutes() * 6,
      o = t.hours() % 12 / 12 * 360 + (a / 12);

  $(".hour").css("transform", "rotate(" + o + "deg)");
  $(".minute").css("transform", "rotate(" + a + "deg)");
  $(".second").css("transform", "rotate(" + s + "deg)");
}

setInterval(clock, 1000);
```

The problem is, after getting to 360 degrees I don't want the variable to keep increasing forever, I just return to 0 and start again, but, CSS makes the hands turn anticlockwise making an undesired effect.

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/tccroo1q/)

I was thinking about removing the *transition* property using JS when im about to go from 360 to 0 and then put it in again, this may be a solution, but I wonder if there is a cleaner way.

Comment: Hey @DomingoSL ... Just a few points. 1) feel free to check out the version that I made [link](http://trevorc.ca/trevorclockanalog.html) .. press CRTL + U to see the source . Also updating every second (1000ms) is not going to work. The problem is just becuase you are updating it every 1000ms does not mean that is the same time the actual time has changed (you will see what I mean later on in your project). Good luck!

Comment: Thank you @TrevorClarke, but you clearly do not understand my approach, please take a look of what "momentjs" is.

Comment: ooo that is beautiful

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done natively. A transition from 356 to 2 degrees will always go counter clockwise. If you don't mind the visible tick from 356 to 2 degrees, just remove the transition. But there's no reason to do that. Try to exploit the fact that `rotate` can take any sane value, also above 360 degrees. So instead of returning to 0, just let the clock continue to increase the value "endlessly" (the highest int value in js is 9007199254740991, so you'll have to refresh the browser after a few million years... :)).

You can keep track of rotations so far in a separate `counter` object outside the setInterval callback like this:

```
var counter = {
  s: 0,
  a: 0,
  o: 0
};

var previous = null;
```

Then you want to store all values from the previous iteration somewhere, and compare the current values to the previous ones. If necessary, increase the appropriate counter by one.

```
if(previous){
  if(s < previous.s){
    counter.s += 1;
  }
  if(a < previous.a){
    counter.a += 1;
  }
  if(o < previous.o){
    counter.o += 1;
  }
}

previous = {
  s: s,
  a: a,
  o: o
};
```

Then just set the multiplied degree value in your inline css. This way you will still have access to the pure values of `s` etc in case you need those for something.

```
$(".second").css("transform", "rotate(" + (s + 360 * counter.s) + "deg)");
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dannyjolie/tccroo1q/6/